# c++ version of python's exec() functions

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-exec

**objective:**
executing a string of c(++) code with some kind of function comparable to the `exec()` function in python.

**example in python:**

```
exec('print("hello world")')
#out:
#hello world
```

**question:**

is there a c++ version of exec in python?

Comment: C can run system commands from the code... But can it compile & run a c code string as well...? C is not interpretible...

Comment: If you want to run system commands you can use system but C/C++ code has to be compiled

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technicall, you (maybe) can. But it's hardly a justifiable effort, there are other scripting languages that can be integrated in C++. For example Lua. Just to think about it, the following could work, if you have a method `int excuteCode(std::string code)`

1. Copy that string into a template that wraps it in some function. The following is an idea of such a template:

```
int userFunc()
{
    %code%
}
```

2. Write the template to a file
3. Build a dynamic library (e.g. a .dll on windows) from that file (call compiler and linker via `system` or OS-specific methods)
4. Load the dynamic library into your running program (again, OS-specific methods)
5. Load the required method `userFunc` and execute it.

Comment: this is briljant

Answer (score 2):

**but, is there a c++ version of exec in python?**

you wan to execute C language statements from a string! so that is not possible with c.

**why**

because c is compiled language, the program first compiled and then executed.
its possible in python as its interpreted language,means program is compiled by
just-in-time compiler at runtime.
hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    system("python -c \"print('hello world')\"");
    return 0;
}
```

For system commands...?